# How to extract subset of data in groups before and after a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I have a text file. In text file based on specific word it should make the data into two groups like everything before specific word as 1 group and every thing after specific word as another group

text file some thing like this

```
hello every one 
Is any space here?

CHAIN

every thing of the 

file lies here
```

Based on CHAIN we separate text file into two groups

```
group 1
hello every one 
Is any space here?
```

```
group 2
every thing of the 

file lies here
```

Comment: you mean use `split`?

Comment: you can split string by keyword, just load your file to some variable, for example `contents`, and call split method with your keyword like 
`contents.split("CHAIN")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try a solution with split ans access each string using index as given below.

```
a = """
hello every one 
Is any space here?

CHAIN

every thing of the 

file lies here
"""

print(a.split("CHAIN")[0])
print(a.split("CHAIN")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you have a text file say `test.txt`.

You code:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

part1, part2 = ("".join(data).split("CHAIN"))
print(part1)
print(part2)
```

Gives me:

```
hello every one
Is any space here?




every thing of the

file lies here
```

Otherwise other solution is also good.

Answer (score 0):

just for completeness (other answers work as well):

if you have a text file

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r').read()

print(file.split('CHAIN'))

# if you want to remove the new spaces (\n)

print([text.strip() for text in file.split('CHAIN')])
```